# Whitespace delimiter not being captured in preg split

Tags: php

```
<?php
    $text = "Testing text splitting\nWith a newline!";
    $textArray = preg_split('/\s+/', $text, 0, PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE);
    print_r($textArray);
```

The above code will output the following:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Testing
    [1] => text
    [2] => splitting
    [3] => With
    [4] => a
    [5] => newline!
)
```

However to my knowledge the PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE flag should be capturing the whitespace delimiters in the array. Am I missing something?

edit: Ok, after rereading the documentation I now understand PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE is not meant for this case. My desired output would be something like:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Testing
    [1] => ' '
    [2] => text
    [3] => ' '
    [4] => splitting
    [5] => '\n'
    [6] => With
    [7] => ' '
    [8] => a
    [9] => ' '
    [10] => newline!
)
```

Comment: Who told you that?

Comment: I mean if that's not the case, then is there a different way?

Comment: According to the php [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php), `PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE` will cause any parenthesized portions of the pattern to be returned as well. What is your desired output?

Comment: @Villa7_ Updated my question, somehow I didn't read that part of the documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So if you read manual for `PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE` once again which says:

> If this flag is set, parenthesized expression in the delimiter pattern will be captured and returned as well.

you will suddenly understand that `expression in the delimiter pattern` (in your case it is `\s`) will be `captured` (i.e added to result) only when it is in `parentheses`. Now, you can:

```
$text = "Testing text splitting\nWith a newline!";
$textArray = preg_split('/(\s+)/', $text, 0, PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE);
                        // parentheses! 
print_r($textArray);
```

Comment: I just figured that out as you answered, haha. Thank you!

Comment: Yeah, me too)))

Answer (score 0):

You can also use [T-Regx library](https://t-regx.com):

```
$textArray = pattern('(\s+)')->split("Testing text splitting\nWith a newline!")->inc();
```